# Proof if Meet-homomorphism and Join-homomorphism satisfies, then it implies order-homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, lattice-orders

What's the proof that join and meet homomorphism lead to order homomorphism as illustrated in this diagram? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhhcm.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/woeEi.jpg

Comment: This kind of post is not encouraged. You should always provide proper context for your question and share your own efforts on solving the problem.

Comment: Notice that the result is not that meet-homomorphism together with join-homomorphism give order-homomorphism, but that each of them do.

Comment: @amrsa oh thanks :)